# Есть конструкция, которая выводит прогресс, но она находится в классе, как правильно сделать, чтобы она была непосредственно в форме

Tags: c#, winforms

Главный вопрос. У меня есть конструкция, которая выводит прогресс в прогрессбар. Там я меняю прогресс через `form.progressBar1.Value=x;` Я хочу избежать этого участка кода, чтобы мой класс FTPDownload не занимался прогрессбаром формы, чтобы это делала сама форма, мне кажется это наиболее правильным  решением. Но я понятия не имею как это правильно сделать) Возможно через событие об изменении переменной, но это для меня темный лес. Вот код вывода в прогрессбар.

```
Progress<FtpProgress> progress = new Progress<FtpProgress>(loadedFile =>
        {
            if (loadedFile.Progress == 100)
            {
                form.progressBar1.Value = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                int x = (int)fileSize * Convert.ToInt32(loadedFile.Progress) / 100;
                form.progressBar1.Value = x;
            }
        });
```

Comment: `Вопрос, который я решил написать, чтобы не создавать второй.` Допустим кто то вник в ваши вопросы и написал вам 2 ответа тут. Вы сможете оба их засчитать, чтобы отвечающий за каждый из них получил по 15 очков? Я вам точно скажу - вы не сможете. Какой тогда смысл кому то постить сюда два ответа, если среди ответов помеченным как решение может быть только один? Вы хотите, чтобы человек, который решит вам помочь, потерял 15 очков потому что вам не хочется задавать свои вопросы отдельно?

Comment: Задайте вопросы отдельно, сделайте пожалуйста заголовок вопроса более понятным. По проводу прогресса - в коллбэк отправляйте готовые данные для вычисления, или готовый `long`, например для `IProgeress<long>`, вызывайте `progress?.Report(ftpProgress.Progress)`. То что в колбэке будут производиться минимальные вычисления - это нормально. Ну либо создайте свойство и переместите вычисления в сеттер.